# MariaDB - Invalid default value for 'created'

Tags: sql, mariadb

I use MariaDB 5.5.68 and I get an error when I try to import database to server

```
#1067 - Invalid default value for 'created'
```

Code part

```
CREATE TABLE `wp_payments` (
  `id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `order_id` varchar(128) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT '',
  `amount` int(10) UNSIGNED DEFAULT '0',
  `phone_number` varchar(128) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT '',
  `created` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `payment_id` varchar(128) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT '',
  `failed_reason` varchar(128) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT '',
  `salt` varchar(128) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT '',
  `status` varchar(36) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT 'pending'
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

How to solve this problem?

Comment: CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as a default for DATETIME type is only available in 10.x. If you're using 5.5, it should a TIMESTAMP column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the type of  column `created` from `datetime` to `TIMESTAMP`

```
CREATE TABLE `wp_payments` (
  `id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `order_id` varchar(128) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT '',
  `amount` int(10) UNSIGNED DEFAULT '0',
  `phone_number` varchar(128) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT '',
  `created` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `payment_id` varchar(128) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT '',
  `failed_reason` varchar(128) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT '',
  `salt` varchar(128) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT '',
  `status` varchar(36) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT 'pending'
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

[**DB Fiddle Demo**](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/p6xBgAX4fNFa17qgnwGBp4/0)